# Mix an HSLA color with white and convert to non-alpha HSL with Chroma.js

Tags: javascript, colors, accessibility, rgba

I have a design system with many, many colors. I have created a table of colors where all colors are mixed with every other color and color contrast ratio (CCR) of each combination is output. The goal is to flag inaccessible color combinations.

I am using Chroma.js to manipulate the colors and output the CCRs. It works brilliantly with the bulk of my HSL-defined colors.

The trouble comes when my design system uses a color with an alpha channel. Determining how a pair of colors performs with CCR when one or both of them are transparent is problematic. I am trying a few different things to mix or blend a HSLA color with white and then run the contrast function on that. Here is a snippet of what I am doing:

```
// where either foreground or background has an alpha value present less than 1
var background = chroma.mix(background, '#fff', 1, 'lab').css();
var foreground = chroma.mix(foreground, background, 1, 'lab').css();
var ccr = chroma.contrast(foreground, background);
// lab gets the closest but not the same as the way CSS overlays colors
```

The results are visualized with this graphic I put together. Left are two colors with an overlay of them in the middle. In Adobe Illustrator, I used 25% transparency on the tan color and a "normal" blend mode. I did the same in CSS and then screen-shotted it, then measured the resulting color mix in Photoshop. To the right are the outputs of Chroma color functions:

[image: Visualization of the different programmatic blend modes]

Having tried what I understand to be the options in Chroma.js, I am wondering what else I can try to get my results closer to the browser output so that my CCR tests will be accurate. Thanks all.

---

Thanks to the accepted answer from @GrahamRitchie, my output table now looks like this. The little "composite" labels show the colors that were produced by these functions, while the main output still layers the transparent colors over each other and the background.

[image: Samepl output from the giant table that this code helps support]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know how to do this with the library you mentioned (Chroma.js) but hopefully a vanilla JavaScript function will help.

Please note that the below function always assumes an opaque background colour to work correctly (hence background RGB and foreground RGBA).

If you need to work with 2 colours that both have alpha channels you would run the function on the background colour first (as the foreground colour) with a white background and then combine the two colours.

The function will also combine two RGB colours, simply omit the alpha channel when passing your RGB colour (`convertToRGB({r,g,b}, {r,g,b})`)

```js
function convertToRGB(frontRGBA, backgroundRGB){

var rtrn = {};
//allows the function to just accept a front colour and assume the background is a plain white.
backgroundRGB = backgroundRGB || {r:255,g:255,b:255};

//allows a RGB value to be passed in assuming full alpha channel.
frontRGBA.a = frontRGBA.a || 1;

//normalise the alpha channel across the foreground and background.
rtrn.r = ((1 - frontRGBA.a) * backgroundRGB.r) + (frontRGBA.a * frontRGBA.r);
rtrn.g = ((1 - frontRGBA.a) * backgroundRGB.g) + (frontRGBA.a * frontRGBA.g);
rtrn.b = ((1 - frontRGBA.a) * backgroundRGB.b) + (frontRGBA.a * frontRGBA.b);

//just check that we don't end up with a value greater than 255 for any channel.
rtrn.r = (rtrn.r > 255) ? 255 : rtrn.r;
rtrn.g = (rtrn.g > 255) ? 255 : rtrn.g;
rtrn.b = (rtrn.b > 255) ? 255 : rtrn.b;

return rtrn;

}


var backgroundRGB = {r:165,g:193,b:211};
var frontRGBA = {r:210,g:203,b:178,a:0.25};

//used for example
var rgb = convertToRGB(frontRGBA, backgroundRGB); 
document.querySelector(".output").style.background = "rgb(" + rgb.r + "," + rgb.g + "," + rgb.b + ")";
document.querySelector(".output").innerHTML = "Output<br/>R:" + rgb.r + "<br/>G:" + rgb.g + "<br/>B:" + rgb.b;
```

```css
.container div{
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   float: left;
}
.div1{
    background: rgba(165,193,211,1);
}
.div2{
    background: rgba(210,203,178,0.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="div1">Background<br/>R:165<br/>G:193<br/>B:211<br/>A:1</div>
<div class="output">Output</div>
<div class="div2">Foreground<br/>R:210<br/>G:203<br/>B:178<br/>A:0.25</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic, I will give this a try this morning.

Comment: This is excellent, thank you. I converted the code into something that will accept the way Chroma outputs RGB values but the core of the math was a very helpful. I'll post an image of the results.

Comment: super, glad it helped and the project looks interesting!

Comment: A little background… this is for a government suite of sites. There will be 6 color themes for site owners to choose from, each supporting a dark mode. Because of all this, a reference for CCR when building themes was support important. We are using Pattern Lab to manage the design themes and this table is in there. This will eventually be 70+ sites using these themes. Transparent colors give us a LOT of flexibility in layering, but pose challenges when measuring CCR as I noted. Tools like WAVE will flag false negatives, but our data needs to show how these colors should really be measured.

Comment: That is an interesting project! [If you plan on using gradients you may find this answer useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60066009/2702894) for making decisions about whether they will pass colour contrast.